# Mysql 8 event scheduler timezone

Tags: mysql, jobs, event

I'm a bit confused about the **event scheduler**. First off, it is running and working, but the timezone handling confuses me a bit, as it seems it's not what is documented on [events metadata](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-metadata.html)

- It says that mysql.event table holds event data as well. This table does not exist in our system.
- It also says in the info schema, **starts** and **last_executed** are displayed as event **timezone**, but that doesn't seem to be the case in our system either.

`starts = reported as 'system' time zone`, currently UTC -0400, hence I had to make the start time -4 hours to have it run in UTC at the start of next month (2019-07-31 20:00:00).

I know I can set the session timezone to UTC.
While that works, as soon as you edit the event, the old gets deleted and a new **create** event is triggered by **phpmyadmin** ( possibly bug? ).

I also know I can run the commands in SQL tab with alter an event, but I am not the only one accessing the system, and anyone could basically use the event interface to edit the event = back to the system timezone

**timezone** reported after adding is system (UTC -4).
On a test run, last_executed was in UTC (no problem really, but it's not what docs say)

Now docs say mysql.event displays the start used to add the event in utc ( again our system not has this table ) and stores the timezone used to prevent wrong timings when changing timezones

What happens when we possibly change the system timezone at a later point? since info schema reports as system and not -0400 what would happen to our event which right now has a starts time of 31.07.2019 20:00:00?

Say we change to utc, would the starts column update to reflect this change? Would the timezone reflect the change?

I'm afraid our event would then possibly run at 8pm in utc instead of -0400, since timezone in info schema might still be 'system' then.

Anyone has some insight on this?
Don't really want to mess with the global timezone to test this out, since system is in production.

Appreciate any help/insights on this,
Seb

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3698

Currently, all datetime values specified in CREATE EVENT are converted to UTC
time zone internally.

Comment: You could improve your answer by quoting the relevant text here - but don't delete the link